# Onclick works only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list in HTML which looks like

```
<a onclick="open_file()" id="3.txt">3.txt</a>
```

My `open_file()` function is looking this

```
function open_file() {
    $("a").click(function (event) {
        var file_name = event.target.id;
        $("#f_name").val(file_name);
        $.ajax({
            url: "docs/" + file_name,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#text_form").val(data);
                $('#text_form').removeAttr('readonly');
                $('#delete_button').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#save_button').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

The problem is function finally loads data into all fields(`text_form` and `f_name`) only after two clicks on such link. It works even if I at first click on one file, then click on another and it loads. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: First click runs `open_file()`. Subsequent clicks run the click handler put in place by `open_file()`.

Comment: We need to see your HTML to figure out a proper way to fix it. i.e what is `#text_form`, `#delete_button`, '#save_button`, etc - also remember, you are making AJAX calls (i.e. asynchronous) so you must wait for the server's response and handle it accordingly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're currently doing is adding an onclick event to a link that calls a function *that adds another onclick event via jQuery*.

Remove the `onclick` property and the `open_file()` function wrapper so that jQuery adds the event as you intended.

Comment: I've modified my code according to your advice and now Chrome debugger just says "$ is not defined" on this line "$("a").click(function (event)"

Comment: My guess is that you haven't loaded jQuery when the page has loaded. See [their documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for more info on that.

Comment: So I have to surround my event listener with "$( document ).ready(function() {"?

Comment: Yes, and all future jQuery code. Exceptions are defining functions and variables which are standard Javascript. If you evoke a function that has jQuery syntax outside of the $(document).ready({}) wrapper, Javascript will throw an error as jQuery is not ready to run.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `onclick="open_file()"` this:

```
<div id='linkstofiles'>
    <a id="3.txt">3.txt</a>
    //other links go here
</div>

$("#linkstofiles a").click(function (event) {
    var file_name = event.target.id;
    $("#f_name").val(file_name);
    $.ajax({
        url: "docs/" + file_name,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#text_form").val(data);
            $('#text_form').removeAttr('readonly');
            $('#delete_button').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#save_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind a click event again in the function when you have `onclick` in your html.

Also for `$ is not defined`, you need to put jquery library in the head.

Comment: May the problem be because I've included jquery file after including my JS file in HTML page?

Comment: Yes, you need to put the jquery file first and then your file.